# PrestaShop CMS Bug

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, dropdown

I installed PrestaShop on the localhost. 
I followed instructions from YouTube tutorial (watch?v=60_jitU6jbM)
Everything seems to be alright except the one thing.
Some of PrestaShop (1.7.6) CMS dropdowns are bugged and not responsive.
Where is the root of a problem? How to fix this?

Image of issue:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the browser's devtools and check the console tab for some red colored messages; if any post them.

Comment: None of these come from Prestashop. Did you try install it with a third-party tool like Softaculous or similar? Cause it seems you don't reach your Prestashop site, I mean judging from the console output. I any case these error messages have nothing to do with Prestashop apparently.

Comment: I would advise you delete everything from the install directory, download the latest 1.7.6.4 and install it from scratch, it'll only take minutes; just unarchive the package and point your browser to the domain you use for this install.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall it multiple times. In fact, I just recently noticed the answer from GitHub.

"Wrong PHP Version - Prestashop 1.7.6 is only compatible to PHP 7.2. You need to downgrade your PHP version."

I don't know yet how to downgrade but I will try.

Comment: If you're using PHP7.3 then this is correct;  on Linux depending of your distribution is easy to add PHP7.2 along other PHP version and switching to it. That goes for macos too as for Win I confess I avoid it for many years now. I am sure you can find info about that on the web. If you're on Linux and mention the distribution you're on I can point you to the right howtos.